# Showing Error while using train_test_Split method to on Kaggle kernal. Help appreciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, kernel

Can any one expalin what is the error and how to aviod?
The same code actually works in my Jupyter and Spider environment. Also
I didn't understand why this isn't working on kaggle kernel.

Below is my code.

```
# Prepare X and y objects for sikitlearn
X = df.iloc[:, 1:5].values
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

# Splitting the Dataset into the training set and the test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state =4)
```

Error Details:

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-49-5647b5a0596a> in <module>()
      1 # Splitting the Dataset into the training set and the test set
      2 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 3 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state =4)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2100 
   2101     return list(chain.from_iterable((safe_indexing(a, train),
-> 2102                                      safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2103 
   2104 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2100 
   2101     return list(chain.from_iterable((safe_indexing(a, train),
-> 2102                                      safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2103 
   2104 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
    183                                    indices.dtype.kind == 'i'):
    184             # This is often substantially faster than X[indices]
--> 185             return X.take(indices, axis=0)
    186         else:
    187             return X[indices]

TypeError: take_nd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: Looks like you have encountered [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5967). Try updating your scikit-learn, numpy and pandas. Show the dtypes for the `df`. Are any of the columns of categorical type in pandas DataFrame?

Comment: I find the solution , I just removed ".values" from my code and  it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe because the type of your target variable is not categorical, you have to change it into labels.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug that has not yet been resolved.

To make the code work, your response variable should not be categorical.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_frame, y_was_categorical.astype(str), stratify=y_was_categorical, test_size=0.2)
```

This is the code that worked in my case